# How to use Node.js with PhoneGap?

Tags: node.js, phonegap

I am able to write HTML, CSS and client-side JavaScript when using PhoneGap

But How can we use Server-side technology - for example : Node.js - in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap apps can only use HTML, CSS, and JS. If you need to use server-side technology, you can use network protocols to communicate with a backend written in your language of choice (node.js in this case). This will require the device to have an internet connection so be sure to check for that and handle any problems with the request.